# Loop to calculate price returns

Tags: r, return-value

i have below code to calculate and make a data.frame with log retunrs of my close prices table. For some reason i get only 0 values. Not sure if the issue is on the n value or i value.

```
 number <- c(1:505)
    n <- nrow(data_all)
    for (i in number)
    {returns <- log(data_all[2:n, i]) - log(data_all[1:(n-1), i])
    if (i == number[1]) returns_all <- returns else
      returns_all <- merge(returns_all, returns)
rm(returns)    
}
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42995937/edit

Comment: `returns_all <- log(data_all[-1,number]) - log(data_all[-n,number])` if data_all is a matrix. Otherwise you can use `as.matrix(...)`

Comment: Hi Jogo, yes data_all is a matrix and i want to apply the calculations to each column by rows. So first column apply the formula log(x+1) - log(x), and then jump to the next column.

Comment: That is what my code do. There is no need to do it one by one (column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `log(a) - log(b) = log(a/b)` you can use `diff` and `log` functions to calculate 
returns of a price series as follows:

For more than one series, I would recommend converting the series to `xts` series

```
library("xts")

#if closePx is price series with first column as date with format = 2002-02-12
#specify the corresponding date format , %Y-%m-%d, 
#2002/02/12 => %Y/%m/%d
#closePx_xts = xts(closePx[,-1],order.by = as.Date(closePx[,1],format="%Y-%m-%d")

library("quantmod")

#create environment to store price data
stockNames = c("IBM","MSFT")
dataEnv = new.env()
getSymbols(stockNames, env = dataEnv, from = "2002-01-01", to = "2010-01-01")

#check prices

ls(dataEnv)

head(dataEnv$IBM)
head(dataEnv$MSFT)



#combine closing prices, using Cl function on each list member get closing price 
#for each stock and use merge.xts to combine prices
#if you have missing prices checkout `zoo::na.locf` function
#i.e. na.locf function from zoo package

closePx = do.call(merge.xts,lapply(dataEnv,Cl))

#closePx = Cl(IBM)

#log returns
logRet = diff(log(closePx))


head(logRet)
#              IBM.Close   MSFT.Close
#2002-01-02           NA           NA
#2002-01-03  0.017621634  0.032144867
#2002-01-04  0.015566342 -0.004778131
#2002-01-07 -0.012417504 -0.004946962
#2002-01-08  0.005226094  0.011889353
#2002-01-09 -0.001685453 -0.009703864
```

With lag function you can calculate discrete/arithmetic returns as follows

```
#discrete returns
discRet = closePx/lag(closePx) - 1


head(discRet)
#              IBM.Close   MSFT.Close
#2002-01-02           NA           NA
#2002-01-03  0.017777811  0.032667094
#2002-01-04  0.015688128 -0.004766734
#2002-01-07 -0.012340725 -0.004934746
#2002-01-08  0.005239774  0.011960312
#2002-01-09 -0.001684034 -0.009656933
```

Also  `PerformanceAnalytics` package for more utility functions

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. One question more, you have only one column, how to apply it for a data.frame with more than one column?

Comment: You just have to combine the series in `xts` series object, I have updated the example above

Answer (score 0):

I make a demo.according to your question.
code is

```
data_all <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = runif(10000,1,50),ncol = 505))
number <- c(1:505)
n <- nrow(data_all)
for (i in number)
{
  returns <- log(data_all[2:n, i]) - log(data_all[1:(n-1), i])
  if (i == number[1]) 
    returns_all <- returns 
  else
    returns_all <- merge(returns_all, returns)
}
```

I recommend you can do as follow,

```
data_all <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = runif(10000,1,50),ncol = 505))
number <- c(1:505)
n <- nrow(data_all)
returns_all <- NULL #I add
for (i in number)
{
  returns <- log(data_all[2:n, i]) - log(data_all[1:(n-1), i])
  returns_all <- cbind(returns_all,returns) #I add
}
```

I hope I can help you.

Comment: Hi, merge function is not giving me troubles, just applying the formula of lag(x+1) - log(x) into every single column for all rows is not working out for me

Comment: x include NA? inf?

Comment: remove NA then it run successfully? or you define how to calculate NA.

Comment: i apologise if i wasted your time, but i actually found an easier way to do it. Simply using {returns_all <- diff.xts(data_all,log = TRUE)} will calculate every single value in the data.frame.

Comment: Thank you~! but I think `diff.xts()` may use parameter to consider how to deal with NA. You should be careful for NA.

Comment: Ok, i checked and it seems because it is xts data.frame the NA are ignored until you reach a numerical value`head(returns_all)
           HBI.Close    MMM.Close
2005-03-22        NA           NA
2005-03-23        NA -0.003637399
2005-03-24        NA  0.002465502
2005-03-28        NA -0.001290713
2005-03-29        NA -0.006124103
2005-03-30        NA  0.015589614`